# How opencl work with opencv

Tags: opencv, opencl

I'm trying to create a region groiwing algorithm using OpenCL,for that i will open one image using OpenCV. The problem is how transform the data into OpenCL.

I'm using opencv version : 2.4.9 and opencl : AMD APP SDK\2.9-1 in visual studio

Would someone tell me after openning the image using opencv what should i do

Answer (score 2):

Generally, there are two ways in order to transfer images (or any other data) from host program to device program in OpenCL applications: 1-Using Buffers 2- Using Image2d.
Both of them use `cl_mem` type. Because using buffer is simpler than using image2d (especially in gray-scale images), I explain how to transfer images from host program to device using buffers in OpenCL.

After reading input image by the openCV object `Mat`, convert it to a gray-scale image. Then, we use the method `clCreateBuffer` which returns a `cl_mem` buffer. We can simply pass `data` (a property of `Mat` obeject) to the `clCreateBuffer` to initialize our input kernel buffer by input image data. Then we can transfer created buffer to kernel using `clSetKernelArg` method. Finally, when kernel finish its job, we can read the results by `clEnqueueReadBuffer`.

Read the comments to understand this code and don't hesitate to ask questions.

Host code:

```cpp
// Make Contex, Kerenl and other requirements for OpenCL before this section....

Mat image = imread("logo.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // reading input image by opencv to Mat type
Mat input_;

cvtColor(image, input_, CV_BGR2GRAY); // convert input image to gray scale

cl_mem inputSignalBuffer = clCreateBuffer(
    context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, input_.rows *input_.cols *input_.elemSize(),
    static_cast<void *>(
        input_.data), // inputSignalBuffers will be initialized by input_.data which contains input image data
    &errNum);

cl_mem outputSignalBuffer =
    clCreateBuffer( // make and preparing an empty output buffer to use after opencl kernel call back
        context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, input_.rows *input_.cols *input_.elemSize(), NULL, &errNum);
checkErr(errNum, "clCreateBuffer(outputSignal)");

errNum = clSetKernelArg(
    kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem),
    &inputSignalBuffer); // passing input buffer and output buffer to kernel in order to be used on device
errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &maskBuffer);
errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &outputSignalBuffer);
errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_uint), &input_.rows);
errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_uint), &input_.cols);
errNum |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, sizeof(cl_uint), &maskWidth);

size_t localWorkSize[2] = {16, 16}; // Using 2 dimensional range  with size of work group 16
size_t globalWorkSize[2] = {
    input_
        .rows, // Note: Global work size (input image rows and cols) should be multiple of size of work group.
    input_.cols};

// Queue the kernel up for execution across the array
errNum =
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( // enqueue kernel with enabling host blocking until finishing kernel execution
        queue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
checkErr(errNum, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel");

Mat output_ = cv::Mat(input_.rows, input_.cols, CV_8UC1);

errNum = clEnqueueReadBuffer( //  reading from ourput parameter of kernel
    queue, outputSignalBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, input_.rows *input_.cols *input_.elemSize(),
    output_.data, // initialize OpenCV Mat by output_.data which contains output results of kernel
    0, NULL, NULL);
checkErr(errNum, "clEnqueueReadBuffer");

// cut the extra border spaces which has been added in the first part of the code in order to adjust image
// size with Work Group Size;

cv::imwrite("output.bmp", output_); // saving output in image file
```

Kernel code:

```cpp
__kernel void convolve(const __global uchar *const input, __constant uint *const mask,
                       __global uchar *const output, const int inputHeight, const int inputWidth,
                       const int maskWidth) {
  uint sum = 0;

  const int curr_x = get_global_id(0); // current curr_x (row)
  const int curr_y = get_global_id(1); // current curr_y (col)
  int d = maskWidth / 2;

  if (curr_x > d - 1 && curr_y > d - 1 && curr_x < inputHeight - d &&
      curr_y < inputWidth - d) // checking mask borders not to be out of input matrix
    for (int i = -d; i <= d; i++)
      for (int j = -d; j <= d; j++) {
        int mask_ptr =
            maskWidth * (i + d) + (j + d); // you can also use mad24(maskWidth, i+d, j+d) which is faster.
        sum += input[(curr_x + i) * inputWidth + curr_y + j] * mask[mask_ptr];
      }

  sum /= (maskWidth * maskWidth); // miangin gereftan

  sum = clamp(sum, (uint)0, (uint)255); // clamp == min(max(x, minval), maxval)

  output[curr_x * inputWidth + curr_y] = sum;
}
```

Comment: Hi Soheil Shababi Thanks for the answer, but i'am confused where i write this program in opencl, opencv or opencv-cl project because any one of them have his own integration in visual studio, and some words are not familar in the other project like the leading and some functions

Comment: *obeject*? `Contex`? `Kerenl`? `miangin gereftan` ↔ averaging?